What is this usage of かじってる

As far as I know かじる has two meanings: to "nibble/bite" and "to know a little of"
But I'm struggling to place any of the two meanings here. Especially given his conclusion is to attack him fast so he can't dodge (phrasing)

The latter meaning is applicable. かじっている figuratively means having a slight understanding or knowledge of something. The sentence means "That movement...so he knows (a bit of) something", and this "something" refers to some skill related to the movement he just observed.

I see. Given it's an observation and his opinion, should he use よう?

@Kawase_K He can use よう, but I don't think he should use it.
